# Eventbrite API not showing ticket_classes for owned events

Tags: php, api, eventbrite, php-curl

If I go to my page https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?token=XXX there's no `ticket_classes` key as I would expect following https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/quickstart/

I am using my personal OAuth token

This means I have do do a loop within a loop and therefore the process time is massively increased

Am I looking at this the wrong way and/or is there a workaround so I don't have to do 2 loops?

I'm using PHP and cUrl

Answer (score 2):

I need to add `&expand=ticket_classes` to the request!